# Комментарии не отправляются в форму Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, комментарии

При добавлении комментариев через админку, всё работает, но если писать комментарии на самой странице, то при нажатии кнопки отправить, выходит ошибка`IntegrityError at /create-comment/ NOT NULL constraint failed: comments_comment.object_id`

Я предполагаю, что это как то связано с моделью users. Но так как я совсем не разбираюсь в коде, подскажите, что могло вызвать данную ошибку и как её можно исправить

Так же при нажатии на кнопку "ответ" на комментарий, ничего не происходит

[image: Текст]

BASE.HTML_________

```
        {% load comments_tree %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.." integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3">

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
{{ comments|comments_filter }}
<hr>
<div class="col-md-12">
<form action="{%url 'comment_create'%}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token%}
{{ comment_form|crispy }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">

</div>
</div>
</body>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap..." integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".reply".)on('click', function(){
var parentId = $(this).attr('data-id')
$("#form-"+parentId).fadeToggle();
})
$(".submit-reply").on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault()
var parentId = $(this).attr('data-submit-reply')
var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
var text = $("#form-'+id).find('textarea[name="comment-text"]').val();
function getCookie(name) {
let cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
// Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
break;
}
}
}
return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
data = {
user: "{{ request.user.username }}",
parentId: parentId,
text: text,
id: id,
csrfmiddleweartoken: csrftoken
}
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
data: data,
url: "{% url 'comment_child_create' %}",
success: function(data){
window.location.replace('/post-comments')
}
})
})
})
</script>

</html>
```

COMMENTS_TREE.PY___________

```
        from django.template import Library
from django.utils.html import mark_safe


register = Library()


@register.filter
def comments_filter(comments_list):
res = """
<ul> style="list-style-type:none;">
<div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
{}
</div>
</ul>
"""
i = ''
for comment in comments_list:
i += """
<li>
<div class="col-md-12 mb-2 mt-2 p-0">
<small>{author}</small> | опубликовано: {timestamp}
<hr>
<p>{text} | id={id}</p>

<a href="#" class="reply" data-id="{id}" data-parent={parent_id}>Ответить</a>
<form action"" method="POST" class="comment-form form-group" id"form-{id}" style="display:none;">
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comment-text"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-reply" data-id="{id}" data-submit-reply="{parent_id}" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>
</li>
""".format(id=comment['id'], author=comment['author'], timestamp=comment['timestamp'], text=comment['text'], parent_id=comment['parent_id'])
if comment.get('children'):
i += comments_filter(comment['children'])
return mark_safe(res.format(i))
```

MODELS.PY__________

```
        from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class Post(models.Model):

author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Автор', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название поста')
text = models.TextField()
comments = GenericRelation('comment')

def __str__(self):
return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Автор', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст комментария')
parent = models.ForeignKey(
'self',
verbose_name='Родительский комментарий',
blank=True,
null=True,
related_name='comment_children',
on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата создания комметария')
is_child = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
return str(self.id)

@property
def get_parent(self):
if not self.parent:
return ""
return self.parent
```

VIEWS.PY__________

```
        from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import transaction
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm
from .utils import create_comments_tree


def base_view(request):
comments = Post.objects.first().comments.all()
result = create_comments_tree(comments)
comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
return render(request, 'base.html', {'comments': result, 'comment_form': comment_form})


def create_comment(request):
comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
if comment_form.is_valid():
new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
new_comment.user = request.user
new_comment.text = comment_form.cleaned_data['text']
new_comment.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model='post')
new_comment.objects_id = 1
new_comment.parent = None
new_comment.is_child = False
new_comment.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect('/post-comments')


@transaction.atomic
def create_child_comment(request):
user_name = request.POST.get('user')
current_id = request.POST.get('id')
text = request.POST.get('text')
user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
content_type = ContentType.objects.get(models='post')
parent = Comment.objects.get(id=int(current_id))
is_child = False if not parent else True
Comment.objects.create(
user=user, text=text, content_type=content_type, object_id=1,
parent=parent, is_child=is_child
)
comments_ = Post.objects.first().comments.all()
comments_list = create_comments_tree(comments_)
return render(request, 'base.html', {'comments': comments_list})
```

Comment: попробуйте без этой строчки ```new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)``` в вашем views.py

Comment: не помогло ____

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в поле со связью статьи и комментария `null=True`

Answer (score 1):

Была ошибка в `objects_id`  нужно было `object_id`
И `users`, а нужно было `users_id`